# How to start the Composer REST Server with the identity created through REST API?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have configured my local REST server to use GitHub auth and Mongo DB. I have followed the deployment steps and can authenticate my GiHub ID putting the default Wallet into the Mongo DB. I then create a participant and issue an identity for that participant. I add the identity to the wallet and set that identity as the default. I was able to do a system/ping to return the current participant and also was able to call REST APIs. 
Now I would like to start REST server with single user mode with identity which I created in the deployment steps as follow.

```
composer-rest-server -i nomura -s twidKDZiYFGw -m false -a false
```

I assume Blockchain identity specified on the command line at startup is created when issuing an identity for the participant.
But it shows the following error.

```
Discovering types from business network definition ...
Connection fails: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The current identity has not been registered:nomura)
It will be retried for the next request.
Exception: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The current identity has not been registered:nomura)
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The current identity has not been registered:nomura)
```

What else do I have to do to create valid blockchain id for starting REST server?

Comment: I think you can do a `composer list -n <yournetwork>` (or something similar) that allows you to list all participants and assets. Not sure, if it lists identities as well, but it looks like your identity is not known to the fabric. Is it using the same network and same connection profile?

Comment: Thanks. Well, I did a `composer list` to check my identity being registered correctly and I found my identity in the registry. Also I was trying to connect to the same network using same connection profile. On the other hand, I can start REST server with admin user and I'm afraid that we couldn't start REST server with the identity which create through composer REST APIs.

Comment: Hm.. permissions / identity roles maybe? Not 100% sure how all the identity / wallet stuff works and there's also a few open bugs in regards to this.

Answer (score 0):

your identity is fine. The problem appears to be how you're trying to start the REST server. You need to specify the connection profile (to connect to the business network).

Example syntax (where 'hlfv1' below is my HL Fabric v1 connection profile name) is:

composer-rest-server -p hlfv1 -n my-network -i nomura -s twidKDZiYFGw -m false -a false